# onchange works only from second change

Tags: javascript, onchange

I'm wrote a little script to handle two selects. First one with car brands, second one with car models. 
When i'm changing car brand i need to change car models value on "ALL".

script:

```
function changer(){
        $("#car_brand").change(function(){
            document.getElementById("car_model").value = "ALL";
            this.form.submit()
        });}
```

html where i'm listening for onchange event:

```
<select class="form-control" name="car_brand" id="car_brand"     
onchange="changer()">
    @if ($_REQUEST['car_brand'] != 'ALL')
<optgroup>
<option name="car_brand" value="{{$_REQUEST['car_brand']}}">    
    {{$_REQUEST['car_brand']}}</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup>
    <option value="ALL">{{$text_all}}</option>
</optgroup>
    @else
<option name="car_brand" value="{{$_REQUEST['car_brand']}}">                
{{$text_all}}</option>
    @endif
<optgroup>
    @foreach($carbrands2 as $brands)
        <option value="{{$brands}}">{{$brands}}</option>
    @endforeach
</optgroup>
</select>
```

This code works, but only from second change of select option. How could i get a rid of this and make it working from first change?

Comment: Get rid of the inline `onchange` and the function and just use the jQuery event listener

Comment: where is your car model html?